# Yodlee - How do you determine the correct negative/positive loan and credit card balances?

Tags: yodlee

We notice that some banks return a negative balance for loans (ItemContainer with a ContainerName of LOAN), while other banks return a positive balance. I'm struggling to think of a scenario where a loan can be considered a positive balance. Does Yodlee have any internal way of returning a negative balance, or do we need to handle that ourselves?

For credit cards, again we notice that balances can be returned as a positive value, but should be negative. With credit cards, it is at least possible to have a positive balance (e.g. you put some money on your card before a holiday), so how can we reliably determine when the balance should be actually negative?

Edit: Yodlee scrapes the page correctly. Sometimes a loan will be shown without a minus sign on the end-users banking page, but it is clearly a debt and Yodlee knows it is a loan.

Comment: Are you sure the data is correct?  Verify this first. There has been many times we've had to chase up with Yodlee Support because their data was incorrect.

Comment: Yes, I am sure the data is correct; tested against our own personal bank accounts to verify.

Comment: no are you sure the YODLEE data is correct?  There has been many times I've sent a screenshot of the bank account to Yodlee only to find out Yodlee are parsing the data incorrectly.

Comment: From our testing, yes the amounts are correct, but the values have the wrong sign. Yodlee is scraping the screen correctly, the values are without a minus sign even though it is a loan amount. I've updated the question.